# Where is the fault in this function?

Tags: python, function

```
with open("german.txt") as f:
    words = f.read().split()

for word in words:
    color = word.lower().replace("o", "0").replace("i", "1").replace("s", "5").replace("t", "7")
    if len(word) == 3 or len(word) == 6:
        ok = True
        for c in color:
            if c not in "abcdef0123456789":
                ok = False
                break
        if ok:
            print(word, "#" + color)
```

This program works, but why doesn't it work anymore when I add a function structure to it?

```
with open("german.txt") as f:
    words = f.read().split()
          
            
def replace_letters_with_numbers(word):
    color = word.lower().replace("o", "0").replace("i", "1").replace("s", "5").replace("t", "7")

    
def is_valid_color(word):
    if len(word) == 3 or len(word) == 6:
        ok = True
        for c in color:
            if c not in "abcdef0123456789":
                ok = False
                break
        if ok:
            print(word, "#" + color)
         
for word in words:
    replace_letters_with_numbers(word)
    is_valid_color(word)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Language? Python perhaps? Bit more description than "fault in the function" - i.e. what is it suppose to do

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah python.

It's supposed to change o to 0, i to 1 etc. Then, check if the word, taken from the list of words, is 3 or 6 characters long and if none of the characters isn't one of "abcdef0123456789".

If so, give out the original word, followed by # and the edited word (so it correlates to a hexadecimal color".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "why doesn't it work anymore when I add a function structure to it?" Well, **what happens** when you try using it? Did you get an error message? If so, did you **read** the error message? Do you **understand** the error message? If you don't understand, then what don't you understand about it, specifically? Exactly what are you trying to do, that you don't know how to do?

Comment: Hint: where the code says `def replace_letters_with_numbers(word):` and `replace_letters_with_numbers(word)`, *why did you need* the `word` part on both sides? *What does it do* when you write that? Now, do you see how that also applies to `color`? Also: are you familiar with the `return` keyword in Python? In your own words, what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different issues.

1. Scoping
2. Return values

With your top-down approach, all the variables are defined.
Your functional approach straight up just not doing anything. For example, the `replace_letters_with_number` function is just assigning the new word into a local variable and returning nothing. Basically this function does nothing. One way to solve this is to return the updated word.

```py
def replace_letters_with_numbers(word):
    return word.lower().replace("o", "0").replace("i", "1").replace("s", "5").replace("t", "7")
```

Another issue is that when you run the `is_valid_color` the variable `color` technically does not exist. If we assume that the word being passed intno this function has already been replaced we can change the variable `color` to `word`.

With these approaches we could change how the for loop is executed, by assigning a variable color when we call `replace_letters_with_number`. Resulting in:

```py
for word in words:
    color = replace_letters_with_numbers(word)
    is_valid_color(color)
```

There are other improvements that could be made; however, the main issue was that the variable `color` was not defined.

Comment: This is not *quite* right, in that the existing `is_valid_color` logic still wants to check the original `word` (specifically, compare its length, and use it for the output). It can do so anyway, since `word` is already a global, but that fails to teach the lesson properly.

Comment: `words` is also a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

What I find wrong with your code:

1. your fist function is correct but is does not return anything. this means you cannot use the word resulting from this function in the subsequent functions. (so add )

   return color
2. in your second function you must pass the returned value instead of word. Because word will still be in this case the raw word you read.

Also if you prefer and based on my observation I suggest splitting the functions into 3 for clarity as below. And from you code this is my understanding (correct if i got this wrong)

1. read a series of words  and replace specific letters with numbers
2. filter only words of length 3 and 6
3. filter words from 2 with characters that are within the alpha-numeric characters defined by you.
   The below code does this exactly.

```
def color_word(word):
    color = word.lower().replace("o", "0").replace("i", "1").replace("s", "5").replace("t", "7")
    return color
    
def word_length_is_3_and_6(word):
    ok = False
    if len(word) == 3 or len(word) == 6:
        ok = True
        print(f'{word} has {len(word)} letters \n resulting color from word : {color_word(word)}')
    return ok

def check_alpha_numeric_state(word):
    ok=True
    for each_char in word:
        if each_char not in "abcdef0123456789":
            ok = False
            print('all letters in word are not alphanumeric - [abcdef0123456789]')
            break
        else:
            print(word, "#" + color_word(word))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = ['happil', 'nos', 'Trusts' 'shon']

    for each_word in words:
        colorword = color_word(each_word) #returns the word with replaced letters and numbers
        word_length = word_length_is_3_and_6(each_word) #boolean
        if word_length == True:
            check_alpha_numeric_state(colorword)
```